# BackboneJS HandlebarsJS Display JSON from Spotify JSON

Tags: json, backbone.js, handlebars.js, spotify

I want to display related artists on my Backbone View by using Spotifys API. So far so good, I managed to get the API/JSON data loaded, but I cant get it displayed in my Handlebars template yet, I get an empty HTML template and I dont know what I'm doing wrong?!?

Here is my Backbone Collection:

```
ArtistRelated.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1HY2Jd0NmPuamShAr6KMms/related-artists';
    },      
    parse: function(artists){
        return artists;
    }           
});
```

And my Handlebars HTML:

```
{{#each this}}
  <img src="{{images.url}}" alt="{{name}}">
  <div>
   <h3>{{name}}</h3>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

The API I took as an example:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1HY2Jd0NmPuamShAr6KMms/related-artists

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And importantly what does your render method in your view look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it myself:

After adding/changing the parse method of the collection into:

```
parse: function(response){
    return response.artists;
}
```

and the Handlebars template:

```
{{#each this}}
 <img src="{{this.images.[0].url}}" alt="{{this.name}}">
 <div>
   <h3>{{this.name}}</h3>
 </div>
{{/each}}
```

it now works! :-)